# Does aluminium dissolve in soda glass?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, glass

Specifically, if a piece of aluminized glass is heated to the melting point of the glass will the coating dissolve into it or otherwise react with it?

Comment: I think nothing will happen - you get molten salt polymer and molten metal phases - very different properties.

Comment: @Mithoron would a thermite-like reaction happen? http://blog.teachersource.com/2011/03/02/silicon-from-sand/ or would it have to be well above melting point?

Comment: At least with quartz it's supposed to be hard to trigger - http://www.researchgate.net/publication/257912633_Thermit-type_SiO2-Al_reaction_in_arc_discharge - obtained by arc discharge (!)

Comment: The aluminum would like to oxidize, and may end up grabbing some oxygen from the glass. It will likely end up as a alumina-silicate glass (with the sodium/boron/whatnot as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since soda[-lime] glass is specified, then Al will react with the alkali forming an [aluminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_aluminate), e.g. $\ce{Na2Al2O4}$. This may or may not dissolve in the molten glass, depending on concentration of the aluminate(s), temperature and cooling rate. If it precipitates, the glass would have a "frosted" appearance.

Comment: [sodium aluminosilicate](https://www.science.gov/topicpages/s/sodium+aluminosilicate+glass.html) glasses definitely exist.